# How to make my IP address appear to have a specific prefix (when connecting to a ssh server)?

Tags: ssh, ip, ident

I have ssh access to several machines at our university computing center, but they only allow connections from within university network which means I have to go on campus everytime I need to run a simulation, collect results, etc.

Is there any way to make my IP address have a specific prefix so that ident protocol on that machine allow me access? I don't expect a specific or complete answer just give me hints where should I look.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make your IP address have 'specific prefix'. However, if you have SSH access from outside world to your campus computer, you can use port forwarding to access in-network resources.

Comment: Thanks, but I only have ssh access from inside university (i.e with specific prefix).